Reading input answer from text file
I'm trying to figure out how to read a line from a text file, and use it as the answer to an input question. The text file is password.txt and it reads:
1234

I want it so the program asks me for my password and if I type in "1234" it reads the answer from a text file and gives me a correct or incorrect response.
I've tried:
registeredPasswordTXT = "password.txt"
registeredPassword = open(registeredPasswordTXT, 'r')

mainPASSWORD = input("Enter password now: ")
if mainPASSWORD == registeredPassword:
    print("correct")

elif mainPASSWORD != registeredPassword:
    print("incorrect")

And this always gives me the incorrect response no matter what I type in the input, I type the correct answer in and I get the incorrect response, almost as if it's not checking what is written in the text file.

And what happened when you tried this? what is the question?

it always gives me the incorrect response.

Did you try to debug it? hint: registeredPassword value is not the file content.

almost as if it's not checking what is written in the .txt file not almost, it doesn't.

I'm not sure how how to debug? I don't know what IDE you are using but they all have guides. For example PyCharm

I'm using pycharm, Whenever I run debug it just crashes when i enter the password

@TrickyTaco11 Well then ditch the PyCharm and run it in plain terminal. Use print(registeredPassword) to see that the variable does not contain what you expect.

As stated in the Python I/O tutorial, "open() returns a file object".  Use read() or readline() to read the file contents or a single line, respectively.  You can use strip() to remove any newline characters.
registeredPasswordTXT = "password.txt"

with open(registeredPasswordTXT, "r") as registeredPasswordFile:
    registeredPassword = registeredPasswordFile.readline().strip("\n")

mainPASSWORD = input("Enter password now: ")
if mainPASSWORD == registeredPassword:
    print("correct")

elif mainPASSWORD != registeredPassword:
    print("incorrect")


this worked. Cheers
